# Inheriting a function with typeglobs

Tags: perl, function, inheritance, perl-module, typeglob

Does the first example with the typeglobs have  disadvantages compared to the second example?

```
package Some::Module::Win32;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(public);

use Some::Module;

*_func_one   = \&Some::Module::_func_one;
*_func_two   = \&Some::Module::_func_two;
*_func_three = \&Some::Module::_func_three;

sub public {
    my $s = _func_one();
    for my $i ( 0 .. $s ) {
        say _func_two( $i );
    }
    say _func_three( $s );
}

1;
```

---

```
package Some::Module::Win32;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(public);

use Some::Module;

sub public {
    my $s = Some::Module::_func_one();
    for my $i ( 0 .. $s ) {
        say Some::Module::_func_two( $i );
    }
    say Some::Module::_func_three( $s );
}

1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example *kind of* shows how `Exporter` works: by assigning typeglobs. But there is an important difference: *when* the functions are imported. This is mostly important when a subroutine has a prototype. Prototypes need to be known *during* parsing, and therefore have to be known in the `BEGIN` phase. `use` – which usually calls `import` on the used package – is processed in the `BEGIN` phase.

You should also realize that in your first example, users of your code can now `Some::Module::Win32::_func_one()` whereas this isn't possible in the 2nd example (unless `Some::Module` exports `_func_one`.

Here is a version that imports the function in the correct phase:

```
package Some::Module::Win32;
use strict;
use 5.10.1;  # because `parent` comes with 10.1

use parent 'Exporter';  # optimal way to inherit the `import`.
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(public);

use Some::Module;

BEGIN {
  *_func_one   = \&Some::Module::_func_one;
  *_func_two   = \&Some::Module::_func_two;
  *_func_three = \&Some::Module::_func_three;
}

sub public {
    my $s = _func_one();
    for my $i ( 0 .. $s ) {
        say _func_two( $i );
    }
    say _func_three( $s );
}

1;
```

And if you want to, you can use a module like [`namespace::autoclean`](https://metacpan.org/module/namespace%3a%3aautoclean) to remove any foreign imports from the symbol table once they are no longer needed by you.

Another strategy would be to put the coderefs into *lexical variables*. However, the syntax is a bit ugly, and any prototypes are *completely* ignored:

```
package Some::Module::Win32;
use strict;
use 5.10.1;

use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(public);

use Some::Module;

my $func_one   = \&Some::Module::_func_one;
my $func_two   = \&Some::Module::_func_two;
my $func_three = \&Some::Module::_func_three;

sub public {
    my $s = $func_one->();
    for my $i ( 0 .. $s ) {
        say $func_two->( $i );
    }
    say $func_three->( $s );
}

1;
```

This does not touch the symbol table, and could therefore be considered a very “clean” solution.

Your second version may be more verbose, but it has the advantage of being very explicit, which may make the code easier to understand for a reader or maintainer. It is the solution I often end up using.

- prototypes work correctly
- very readable (unless the full name of the function is insanely long, like `Marpa::R2::Inner::Scanless::G::SYMBOL_IDS_BY_EVENT_NAME_AND_TYPE`)
- unambiguous
- no namespace pollution

Comment: Obviously nothing technical to add, but +1 for the readable. Keep the clever code for when you really need it.